# how to make camera preview square like Instagram

Tags: android, camera, instagram

I tried many Camera preview example but i want to Make it Square Like Instagram.and please Suggest any Filter Like Instagram Link. Thanx

Comment: Create a Custom Camera Surface in your App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library - [Square Camera](https://github.com/boxme/SquareCamera)

Comment: thanx @lance. You saved my day.

Comment: but it is not working , i giving gradle path , every thing but it is not working. Pls help